# Mission control font is aliased in OS X El Capitan

Tags: mission-control, macos

I just upgraded my Mac to 10.11 and noticed the aliased font in Mission Control. I tried to include a screenshot of it, hope the issue is clear.

[image] [image]

The font was fine in Yosemite. Is anybody facing the very same issue? I could not find a proper setting about it in the System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing to my screenshot:

[image]

The font in my OS X 10.11 is all OK.

- Maybe it means it is bold, why Apple changed the font style.  Maybe it
- Maybe be a bug of OS X 10.11. Report it to Apple.

Comment: Late reply, sorry. `:)` I reported it to Apple, but got no feedback from them. Surprisingly, the last update fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, witchcraft followed.

I reported this issue to Apple hoping to get any feedback, but nothing happened. A couple of days later, a system update was released and the issue was fixed.

So, the only concrete advice I can give regarding this particular issue is: make sure to get the last patches installed. `:)`